# How to covert file byte code to file form data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have two folders from one folder i get the file and upload to another server
So when i get file from 1st folder i get a byte code of that file now i want same file to upload in second folder but the rest api of uploading is taking FormData as argument.
I tried this.

I am getting response type blob when downloading file

```
this.testservice.getfile().subscribe((res)=>{
     /*res is byte of file that i download*/
    let formData = new FromData();
    formData.append("name","abc.png")
    formData.append("files",res as any)
    this.testservice.uploadfile(formData).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log("uploaded successfully)
    })
})
```

But why i get is file not found exception so please help me what i can do to convert this byte code to form-data image type

Answer (score 1):

there appears to be a typo `FormData()` and not `FromData()` ?
Can you try again and see if the issue persists.